# Check status of systemd autostart scrips

Tags: systemd, autostart

I'm talking about the autostart scripts placed in `~/.config/autostart`. I know that `systemd-xdg-autostart-generator` creates `.service` files for them. So where do i find the generated files so that i can check their status using systemctl status foo.service

Comment: I think some doc said they are in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/generator/`, which might be `/run/user/<your_uid>/generator`.

Comment: @meuh that is indeed the correct location but i'm unalbe to check their status using `systemctl status` command. Any ideas on how  i could check their status?

Comment: `sudo systemctl status` should list all the running services. Autostart services are for a user, not the system, so you might be able to say `systemctl status --user foo.service`.

Comment: @meuh can you write an answer to this question? correct location was actually $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/generator.late . i would expect you to write the location as well as the command

Comment: Please write-up and accept your own answer with the correct details you have found; I was just providing some possible places to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the generated entries at `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/generator.late`

to check the status
`systemctl status --user foo.service`